# Knights Tour recursive C# Im getting something wrong in my way of doing the stuff

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, knights-tour

```
class Knight
{
    public static readonly double LegalDistance = Math.Sqrt(5);
    public Stack<Field> Steps { get; set; }

    private static readonly List<Field> board = Board.GameBoard;
    private static List<Field> fields;       

    private static readonly Random random = new Random();
    private static readonly object synLock = new object(); 

    public Knight(Field initial)
    {
        Steps = new Stack<Field>();
        Steps.Push(initial);
    }

    public void Move()
    {
        Field destination = Choose();

        if (destination == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Moving from " + GetPosition().GetFieldName() + " to " + destination.GetFieldName());
        Steps.Push(destination);
    }

    public Field Back()
    {
        Field from = Steps.Pop();
        Console.WriteLine("Moving back from " + from.GetFieldName() + " to " + GetPosition().GetFieldName());

        return from;
    }

    public Field Choose()
    {
        List<Field> legalMoves = Behaviour();

        legalMoves.RemoveAll(field => Steps.Contains(field, new FieldValueComparer()));

        if (legalMoves.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Field theChoosenOne;

        int index;
        lock (synLock)
        {
            index = random.Next(0, legalMoves.Count);
        }

        theChoosenOne = legalMoves.ElementAt(index);


        return theChoosenOne;
    }

    private List<Field> Behaviour()
    {
        fields = new List<Field>();
        fields.AddRange(board);

        for (int i = fields.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            double actualDistance = fields[i].GetDistance(GetPosition());
            if (!actualDistance.Equals(LegalDistance))
            {
                fields.Remove(fields[i]);
            }
        }

        return fields;
    }
    public List<Field> GetSteps()
    {
        return Steps.ToList();
    }

    public Field GetPosition()
    {
        return Steps.Peek();
    }
}
```

So this is how I'd do the stuff. The problem is, I am missing some key functionality, because on low given stepcount it backtracks to the start, on high stepcount, it causes StackOverFlow.

Here are some other functions to let you understand what I want to do:
Calculating distance:

```
public double GetDistance(Field other)
{
       return Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(other.X - X, 2) + Math.Pow(other.Y - Y, 2));
}
```

Finding the path:

```
class PathFinder
    {
        public static void FindPath(Knight knight)
        {

            if (knight.Steps.Count != 20)
            {
                knight.Move();

                FindPath(knight);

                knight.Back();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path search is essentially random walk. On large board, this may take a while anyway.

Now about StackOverflow: notice that you don't push anything on `Move()` when there are no places to go. So, on recursive call to `FindPath()` there still will be the same `knight.Steps.Count`, the same position, the same `null` return on `Choose()`... and so on, until you're out of stack space.

Obvious fix would be to add `bool` return value to `Move()` indicating if there *was* any move. Unless there is actual reason behind using random moves, more deterministic search algorithm is recommended.